# Using crontab in Bash

Tags: python, bash

I am looking to use crontab in Bash to run a python script. What I have below does not work.

```
 SHELL=/bin/bash
11 22 * * * username /usr/lib/python2.7 /mnt/c/Users/Eric/Documents/Feedparser/crontab.py
```

Nor did this:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/lib/python2.7
5 22 * * * username python /mnt/c/Users/Eric/Documents/Feedparser/crontab.py
```

Comment: `PATH` is supposed to include _directories_, not executables. You do not need `username` to run the command. The command is run on behalf of the user who saved the crontab

Comment: first try with some dummy cron job and try taking its log.. eg.- 1 * * * * date >> /tmp/crontest.log

Answer (score 1):

You can try logging the output and error of the execution of the command in crontab using :

```
11 22 * * * username /usr/lib/python2.7 /mnt/c/Users/Eric/Documents/Feedparser/crontab.py > /tmp/crontab.log 2>&1
```

This may give you the idea about what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the `username` in your cron command. Otherwise, it will try to run it as an executable with arguments `python /mnt/c/Users/Eric/Documents/Feedparser/crontab.py`

just put :

```
5 22 * * * python /mnt/c/Users/Eric/Documents/Feedparser/crontab.py
```

Comment: It depends on whether this is in the system crontab (generally /etc/crontab; this does have the username field) or a per-user crontab(which doesn't have the username field). See [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/290093/difference-between-etc-crontab-and-crontab-e).

Comment: I've tried with and without the username. Am I correct in adding the shell and path?  Does it really need to know where python 2.7 is?

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to consider making your python file executable and calling it directly. Your crontab would then say:

`5 22 * * * ./mnt/c/Users/Eric/Documents/Feedparser/crontab.py`

or

`5 22 * * * cd /mnt/c/Users/Eric/Documents/Feedparser && ./crontab.py`

To do this, make your file executable:

```
chmod +x /mnt/c/Users/Eric/Documents/Feedparser/crontab.py
```

And add a shebang to the first line of your python file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```